# use Python/C API on msys2-mingw

Tags: python, c++, msys2

I try to use [Python/C API](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/) on msys2-mingw, so I install
this package `mingw-w64-x86_64-python2`, and I write `main.cpp`:

```
#include <python2.7\Python.h>
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

And when I enter this `$ g++ main.cpp -o main`, 
It gives me these msg:

```
In file included from \msys64\mingw64\include/python2.7\Python.h:58:0,
             from main.cpp:1:
\msys64\mingw64\include/python2.7\pyport.h:907:2: 錯誤：#error "LONG_BIT       definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
 #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
  ^
In file included from \msys64\mingw64\include/python2.7\Python.h:8:0,
             from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/cygwin/types.h:78:20: 錯誤：一個宣告指定了多個類型
 typedef __uint32_t uid_t;
                ^
/usr/include/cygwin/types.h:78:20: 錯誤：沒有宣告任何東西 [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/cygwin/types.h:84:20: 錯誤：一個宣告指定了多個類型
 typedef __uint32_t gid_t;
                ^
/usr/include/cygwin/types.h:84:20: 錯誤：沒有宣告任何東西 [-fpermissive]
makefile:2: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

I have no idea why these happen. It's not a error about `linking file`(since I hadn't link any file.). Is my method wrong, or I include the wrong file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mix GCC's: mingw-w64 GCC and msys GCC. For mingw-w64 GCC under MSYS2 you must not have includes from /usr. See your error message **/usr/include/cygwin/types.h**